# Algorithm for grouping identical neighbors in a list

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, data-compression, lists

I have a list that I want to reduce to a smaller list by grouping identical neighbors. This list has many many redundant entries.

Example list:

```
1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

After 'compression'

```
1,2,3,1,2,4,1
```

Is there an algorithm for doing this that is faster than O(n)? In other words, faster than just looking at the next neighbor?

```
while (1)
    n = 0, m = 1
    if (list[n] == list[m])
        remove list[m]
    else 
        n = m
        m = m + 1
    if (m > list.size)
        break
```

If not, what about this problem makes it O(n)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an adversary argument (exercise) to show that any algorithm which outputs the correct "compression" must examine all entries in the input, in *every* case. Such an algorithm cannot run in $o(n)$ on *any* input.

To answer your question, the reason that this problem requires a running time of $\Omega(n)$ is that the output depends on all entries of the input, in the sense that for every input and every entry there is a way to change the entry that affects the output. (Note, however, that not every change to the input results in a change to the output: for example $1,1,2$ and $1,2,2$ have the same output, but $1,3,2$ does not.)